# How create new counter that counts by order of appearance

Tags: counters

I want to create a counter (and be able to label each time a new item of it appears) that counts problems and name them in order of their appearance, indifferent to which section they appear in. Such as:

Problem 1. Text text text equation....

and then in a totally different section/chapter

Problem 2. Text ... equation text etc

And so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply define a new counter

```
\newcounter{problem}
```

and its numbering won't depend on sectioning levels.

But, looking at the result you want to achieve, I suggest you to define a new theorem-like environment

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{problem}\label{prob:first}
  Some text
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}\label{prob:second}
  Some text
\end{problem}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{problem}\label{prob:third}
  Some text
\end{problem}

A reference to problem \ref{prob:second}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT (in response to the OP's comment)

You can define a new style and use it instead of `definition` style:

```
\newtheoremstyle{problem}%  <name>
  {\topsep}%                <space above>
  {\topsep}%                <space below>
  {}%                       <body font>
  {}%                       <indent amount>
  {\bfseries\large}%        <theorem head font>
  {.}%                      <punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}%                   <space after theorem head>
  {}%                       <theorem head spec>
\theoremstyle{problem}
```

Change `\large` to whatever you want.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{problem}%  <name>
  {\topsep}%                <space above>
  {\topsep}%                <space below>
  {}%                       <body font>
  {}%                       <indent amount>
  {\bfseries\large}%        <theorem head font>
  {.}%                      <punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}%                   <space after theorem head>
  {}%                       <theorem head spec>
\theoremstyle{problem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{problem}\label{prob:first}
  Some text
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}\label{prob:second}
  Some text
\end{problem}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{problem}\label{prob:third}
  Some text
\end{problem}

A reference to problem \ref{prob:second}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works great thus far. Is it possible to change the size of the font of the thing that says "Problem 3" in your output example?

Comment: @LoveLearning Yes, see the edit.

Comment: Wow amazing, you're a true Maestro!

Comment: @LoveLearning Thanks for your kind words, but "Maestro" here is someone else than me :-) I'm just a simple LaTeX user with 20 years of experience...